How can I change the default /rpc/ endpoint in Supabase PostgreSQL to a custom endpoint?
I am currently using Supabase with a PostgreSQL database for my application, and I would like to customize the default /rpc/ endpoint for remote procedure calls (RPC). My goal is to create a custom endpoint that better aligns with my application’s requirements.
I have reviewed the Supabase documentation but have not found a clear method to change the default RPC endpoint. Additionally, I am not using the Supabase.js client; instead, I am making direct HTTP requests to the endpoints.
-- Function Definition
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_content(param_episodeid integer)
RETURNS JSON AS $$
DECLARE
    result JSON;
BEGIN
    -- Use COALESCE to handle cases where no rows are found
    SELECT COALESCE(json_agg(row_to_json(t)), '[]'::json) 
    INTO result
    FROM (
        SELECT id, title
        FROM episodes
        WHERE id = param_episodeid
    ) t;

    RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql immutable;

